# How do I implement django-articles app into a new project via pip?

Tags: django, pip, cheeseshop

I'm trying to install the following django app from the cheeseshop:

https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-articles/overview

This is my first day of Django-ing and I'm unsure what to do to get the app's folder populated inside my project.

So far, I've pip installed the app into my virtualenv. This is verified by opening a python shell and getting no errors when I run "import articles"

I've edited the settings.py file and added it to the list of installed apps. I believe this to be OK as I can then run runserver without any "module not found" errors.

syncdb also ran fine.

Where do I go from here?

ie, I would like to have a section of the website called News which uses this app. I have no routes or other apps configured yet, just a clean Django with psycopg2.

**EDIT:** Enabling the default admin site, I can manage the Articles there, but still unsure of how these will be displayed on the site when I have no app folder created for them. When trying to startapp articles, I'm warned it's conflicting name with an existing module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a new app called articles. As you are able to import articles via the python console you have successfully installed it. You can find it in your virtualenv folder in the folder site-packages:

```
/path_to_your_virtualenv/.virtualenvs/<virtualenvname>/lib/<pythonversion>/site-packages
```

You can use this app, installed via pip, as it is an app which lives in your project folder.

Comment: Thanks Tom.

Sorry, I'm still a little unclear as to how to implement this so it can be publicly accessible.

Do I need to create any new apps/models to show the articles at /News/ or simply add some kind of route to the urls file?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now... I'd made my project root above the virtualenv path and had assumed I never touch things in the virtualenv once the project is created. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the articles urls in your own urls.py. Since you say you want it under News, this would do fine:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^news/', include('articles.urls'),
)
```

Note though that the [readme for the articles app](https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-articles/overview) implies that you'll need to create your own base template for it to inherit from. Just create a `base.html` file in a directory called `templates` under your project, give it a basic HTML structure, and put in `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in the relevant place (and the same for the other blocks mentioned in the readme).

You should probably do the Django tutorial anyway, to understand exactly what's going on with the URL and the templates.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

Apologies I can't award two answers or upvote anything with my new account.

When I add such a route in urls.py, I get 

`name 'articles' is not defined`

which I think I need to have an import at the top of that file such as 

`from ?? import articles`

the admin one looks like this:

`from django.contrib import admin`

As the articles folder is in the root of site-packages, how can I reference this for import?

Comment: Make sure you've put `'articles.urls'` in quotes as I have done above, then there's no need to import it. Otherwise you can just do `import articles` since as you say it is directly in site-packages.

Comment: perfect, thank you!

I will re-read the tutorials a few more times I'm sure ;)